# Issues with proxy in Gitlab CI using Docker runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to package my Maven/Java app in a Docker Gitlab CI runner.

I'm behind a corporation proxy. This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-7

build:
  script: "mvn clean package -B"
```

When a build is triggered, I get this error (in the Gitlab build console):

> Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]

Then, I have added

```
variables:
  http_proxy: http://user:pass@corp.proxy.ip:port
```

to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. But I get another error:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxx@170.20.20.20:8080/myapp.git/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 504

When I registered the Docker runner, Docker image selected was `maven:3-jdk-7`.

I have just tried adding `no_proxy` variable with 172.20.20.20 as value (Gitlab IP) but I get the same error (the first one.)

How can I solve it? Is there a way to force the Docker runner (container) to use `--net=host`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was I had to open up the mvnw document. Inside of it I found this line

`MAVEN_OPTS="$(concat_lines "$MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/jvm.config") $MAVEN_OPTS"`

In between the ')' and the $MAVEN_OPTS I placed the

`-Dhttps.proxyHost=yourHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=yourPort`

arguments. This worked for me. Hope this helps. I didn't need the "variables" section you described above.